# testCafe: How to configure the tests in the same spec file, to execute sequentially?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, testcafe

We are using `testCafe` for automation. when it comes to executing tests in parallel, test cafe even executes `test` blocks within the spec file, parallelly.

Our tests are independent, but there are some tests (within the same file) that are interdependent (to save time).
For example:

```
Test1: End to end user journey, to make a purchase
Test2: Go to transaction portal, to check the transaction details (to ensure that the transaction was smooth)
```

So, we have kept the above two tests in the same spec file and want to execute them sequentially. Since, we have a transaction from 1st test, so we want to leverage that in test2; instead of doing it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such feature out of the box. There's been this [discussion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2011) on TestCafe's Github page, it's still open.

One not very nice workaround could be using meta information to filter what tests you want to execute:

```
test
    .meta({ num: '1' })
    ('Test 1', async t => { 

    // some test steps
});

test
    .meta({ num: '2' })
    ('Test 2', async t => { 

    // some test steps
});
```

and execute the tests using [`--test-meta` or `--fixture-meta` options](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--test-meta-keyvaluekey2value2):

```
$ testcafe tests/* --test-meta num=1 && testcafe tests/* --test-meta num=1
```

then you know `Test 1` will be run before `Test 2`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this is what we have for now.